# In IE9 javascript not working, but after open console it work

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, alloy-ui

I have written javascript by using Alloy UI and jquery it is working fine in firefox, chrome and IE 10,11 but IE 9 its not work.

when I open console for debug it working fine.

Comment: check for console errors. may be you are using `console.log()` and it is only activated when console is open in some specific versions of IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably use `console.log` in the code. IE do not have the `console` object. This object exists only when console is open.

try writing (at the begginig of the page/scripts)

```
if (typeof(console) == 'undefined') console = { log: function () {} };
```